# Injecting properties into a python module doesn't work as expected

Tags: python

I am trying to do evil magic with python, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
def inject_imports(self,module):
    m = sys.modules[module]
    for key in self._classdict.keys():
        setattr(m, key, property(lambda : getattr(self, key)))
    for key in self._methoddict.keys():
        setattr(m, key, property(lambda : getattr(self,key)))
```

The reason why i am injecting it in this convoluted way with lambda is that I am emulating a lazy import. The problem is that during runtime, I get the message:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'attribute'
```

It seems that actually, a property object does not actually provide direct access to the attributes, but instead has fget/fset/and so on. How can I fix this? I basically just need a proxy that transparently redirects accesses to itself to the result of a lambda, or something like that.

Comment: As long as you don't want to intercept the "special methods" that are only looked-up at the class level, you could create a module wrapper class that intercepted calls and redirected them as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module` here is an instance of the builtin `module` type. The `property` type relies on the [protocol descriptor](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) and the protocol descriptor is only invoked on class attributes (you can set a `property` (or any other descriptor) as an instance attribute but then it's `__get__` / `__set__` / `__del__` methods won't be invoked).

If you want a proxy using descriptors, you'll have to wrap the module in a proxy class and set your properties on the class instead... But I'm not sure it'll work as expected.